# I don't get why this URL matching regex isn't working

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match Linux kernel amd64 deb hrefs from a raw HTML string, using this regular expression:

```
r'(?<=href=")linux-.*?_amd64\.deb(?=")'
```

The kind of urls I'm trying to match look like this:

```
<a href="linux-headers-3.16.0-031600rc1-generic_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_amd64.deb">
```

However, I only want to extract what is between the `"`s inside of the `href` attribute.
The above regex does match the first href correctly, and then matches a bunch of stuff, including markup.
Removing the `_amd64` from the regex makes it match in fact only URLs, but of course, it doesn't filter out i386 debs:

```
r'(?<=href=")linux-.*?\.deb(?=")'
```

Here's the raw HTML code I'm applying the regex on:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index of /~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-rc1-utopic</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Index of /~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.16-rc1-utopic</h1>
        <table><tr><th><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="[ICO]"></th><th><a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a></th><th><a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a></th><th><a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a></th><th><a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a></th></tr><tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="/~kernel-ppa/mainline/">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"></td><td><a href="0001-base-packaging.patch">0001-base-packaging.patch</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 04:35  </td><td align="right"> 14M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"></td><td><a href="0002-debian-changelog.patch">0002-debian-changelog.patch</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 04:35  </td><td align="right">333K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/text.gif" alt="[TXT]"></td><td><a href="0003-configs-based-on-Ubuntu-3.15.0-7.12.patch">0003-configs-based-on-Ubuntu-3.15.0-7.12.patch</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 04:35  </td><td align="right"> 51K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="BUILD.LOG">BUILD.LOG</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 05:25  </td><td align="right">7.1M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="BUILD.LOG.amd64">BUILD.LOG.amd64</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 05:25  </td><td align="right">2.3M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="BUILD.LOG.armhf">BUILD.LOG.armhf</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 05:25  </td><td align="right">597K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="BUILD.LOG.binary-headers">BUILD.LOG.binary-headers</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 05:25  </td><td align="right"> 22K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="BUILD.LOG.i386">BUILD.LOG.i386</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 05:25  </td><td align="right">2.3M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="BUILT">BUILT</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 05:25  </td><td align="right">108 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="CHANGES">CHANGES</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 04:35  </td><td align="right">744K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="CHECKSUMS">CHECKSUMS</a></td><td align="right">09-Jun-2015 11:36  </td><td align="right">3.1K</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="CHECKSUMS.gpg">CHECKSUMS.gpg</a></td><td align="right">09-Jun-2015 11:36  </td><td align="right">490 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="COMMIT">COMMIT</a></td><td align="right">29-May-2015 11:09  </td><td align="right"> 51 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/hand.right.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="README">README</a></td><td align="right">12-Jun-2015 13:45  </td><td align="right">622 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="SOURCES">SOURCES</a></td><td align="right">12-Jun-2015 13:45  </td><td align="right">237 </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="linux-headers-3.16.0-031600rc1-generic_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_amd64.deb">linux-headers-3.16.0-031600rc1-generic_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_amd64.deb</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 04:55  </td><td align="right">1.1M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="linux-headers-3.16.0-031600rc1-generic_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_i386.deb">linux-headers-3.16.0-031600rc1-generic_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_i386.deb</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 05:15  </td><td align="right">1.0M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="linux-headers-3.16.0-031600rc1-lowlatency_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_amd64.deb">linux-headers-3.16.0-031600rc1-lowlatency_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_amd64.deb</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 04:56  </td><td align="right">1.1M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="linux-headers-3.16.0-031600rc1-lowlatency_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_i386.deb">linux-headers-3.16.0-031600rc1-lowlatency_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_i386.deb</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 05:17  </td><td align="right">1.0M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="linux-headers-3.16.0-031600rc1_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_all.deb">linux-headers-3.16.0-031600rc1_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_all.deb</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 04:36  </td><td align="right"> 12M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="linux-image-3.16.0-031600rc1-generic_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_amd64.deb">linux-image-3.16.0-031600rc1-generic_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_amd64.deb</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 04:55  </td><td align="right"> 51M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="linux-image-3.16.0-031600rc1-generic_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_i386.deb">linux-image-3.16.0-031600rc1-generic_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_i386.deb</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 05:15  </td><td align="right"> 51M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="linux-image-3.16.0-031600rc1-lowlatency_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_amd64.deb">linux-image-3.16.0-031600rc1-lowlatency_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_amd64.deb</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 04:56  </td><td align="right"> 51M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="linux-image-3.16.0-031600rc1-lowlatency_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_i386.deb">linux-image-3.16.0-031600rc1-lowlatency_3.16.0-031600rc1.201406160035_i386.deb</a></td><td align="right">16-Jun-2014 05:17  </td><td align="right"> 51M</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><th colspan="5"><hr></th></tr>
        </table>
        <address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at kernel.ubuntu.com Port 80</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using `re.findall(pattern, rawHTMLString)` for this. What is wrong with the regex?

Comment: If you want to get some data from a HTML file, I recommend use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup).

Comment: Looks cool. Will check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=href=")linux-[^"]*?_amd64\.deb(?=")
```

Your .*? seems to be too greedy, so skipping quotes will at least skip going past the quoted areas.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that it starts matching a URL that starts with `linux-`, but doesn't have `_amd64.deb`, and then the match continues until it finds `_amd64.db` in another URL. So the match contains everything in between those two URLs. You need to replace

```
.*?
```

with something that prevents matching markup in between URLs. You can use

```
[^"]*
```

since you're matching the text between quotes, so the match can't contain quotes.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uL9rM5/2)

Comment: Thanks. Wish I could upvote this. Great explanation.

Comment: @msw Did you downvote both answers because we gave a regexp answer to a regexp question, instead of telling him to use a DOM library? If you think there's a better way to answer, you should post it.